# Date time format in UNIX crontab

Tags: unix, datetime, cron

I'm running a cron every 6 hours to backup my database.
I want the filename to contain the date & time it was created in the following format:

```
mysqlbackup_22/5/2013_15:45.sql.gz
```

This is the command I run:

```
date=`date -d`; mysqldump -uusername -ppassword dbname | gzip > /path/to/dir/mysqlbackup_$date.sql.gz
```

What do I need to change `date -d` to?

Comment: Use this: `date "+%Y_%H:%M"`

Comment: Should it be date=\`date +%Y_%H:%M\`?

Comment: Yes, but with quotes. Also `date=$(date "+%Y_%H:%M")`. Take into consideration semicolon is not very UNIX friendly for names.

Comment: Gives an error: `/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching \`"'`

Comment: Update your question with the code, so we can see what can be going wrong.

Comment: I simply changed `date=\`date -d\`` to `date=$(date "+%Y_%H:%M")`

Comment: Yes, exactly what I meant. Did it work?

Comment: Like I said, it throws an error: `/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching \`"' `

Comment: the "+" has to be outside the quotation marks.

Answer (score 13):

If you use a date format like `date +"%d-%m-%Y_%H:%M"` in your crontab you may need to escape the `%` characters with a backslash, like this: `date +"\%d-\%m-\%Y_\%H:\%M"`.

Many crons handle `%` specially by replacing them with newline and sending the following text as stdin to the command before it. See `man 5 crontab` for details.

Comment: Thanks! I had tried to many things but didn't notice this one. I moved from an older version of CentOS to a newer and I guess the newer version requires the escapes on the % characters. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `+` operator on `date` gives you the flexibility to specify the date in whatever way/format you want, as long as there's a variable for what you want. In this case, from `man date`:

```
   %d     day of month (e.g, 01)
   ...
   %H     hour (00..23)
   ...
   %m     month (01..12)
   %M     minute (00..59)
   ...
   %Y     year
```

So, you'd have:

```
date +"%d/%m/%Y_%H:%M"
```

Or, applying to your command:

```
date=`date +"%d-%m-%Y_%H:%M"`; mysqldump -uusername -ppassword dbname | gzip > /path/to/dir/mysqlbackup_$date.sql.gz
```

Note that I changed the forward slashes (`/`) in filenames to dashes (`-`) as you can't have forward slashes in unix/linux filenames.

Comment: Using / in the name is fine as long as all those directories already exists. You could create them by running `$(mkdir -p $(dirname $date))`

Comment: I believe the slashes were intended to be part of the filename, not part of the path. Only OP can confirm..... :-/